# hacer autoincrement, en un trigger, de forma automatica

Tags: mysql, oracle

la cosa es que mi profesor, a partir de la tabla **'reserva'** la cual me ha facilitado el, el valor, **'id_reserva'** es **autoincrement**, pero necesito que me genere un valor automático, pero **el trigger** que me pide realizar, quiere que cada vez que tengamos una nueva alta de un usuario jugador, debemos hacer una reserva de una clase (tipo
**‘test de nivel’**) con un profesor en **la primera pista** que quede **libre a partir de las 24 horas de su alta.**
adjunto tabla reserva ,clase y Jugador. Gracias de antemano.

```
CREATE TABLE `reserva` (
    `id_reserva` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `usuario_reserva_login` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    `id_pista` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
    `fecha_reserva` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'fecha de la reserva',
    `tiempo_reserva` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'tiempo que se reserva la pista (60;90) minutos' ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_reserva`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `Unique_reserva` (`usuario_reserva_login`, `fecha_reserva`, `id_pista`) USING BTREE
)
COMMENT='Tabla de las reservas de las pista'
COLLATE='utf8mb4_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `clase` (
    `profesor_login` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    `id_reserva` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id de la reserva de pista',
    `tipo_clase` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'saque; bandejas; voleas;.......texto explicativo' ,
    `jugador_login_1` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    `jugador_login_2` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `jugador_login_3` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `jugador_login_4` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`profesor_login`, `id_reserva`, `tipo_clase`) USING BTREE
)
COMMENT='Tabla de las clases de padel del club'
COLLATE='utf8mb4_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `jugador` (
    `login` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
    `posicion_en_pista` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'reves, drive, ambas' ,
    `nivel_de_juego` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'de 1 a 7',
    PRIMARY KEY (`login`) USING BTREE
)
COMMENT='Tabla con la información de los jugadores'
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

y aquí lo que tengo yo realizado. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS nuevo_jugador $$
CREATE TRIGGER nuevo_jugador AFTER INSERT ON jugador
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


   SET @vres = (SELECT p.id FROM pista AS p, reserva AS r
                      WHERE p.id = r.id_pista
                      AND r.fecha_reserva <= NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR 
                      GROUP BY p.id
                      LIMIT 1); 
      # cogemos el id de la pista que este libre de aqui a 24 horas



    INSERT INTO reserva (id_reserva ,usuario_reserva_login, id_pista,fecha_reserva, tiempo_reserva) VALUES ((SELECT max(r.id_reserva)+1 FROM reserva AS r 
                      WHERE usuario_reserva_login = r.usuario_reserva_login
                      ORDER BY id_reserva ASC),NEW.login ,@vres, NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR , 90);INSERT INTO reserva (id_reserva ,usuario_reserva_login, id_pista,fecha_reserva, tiempo_reserva) VALUES ('""',NEW.login ,@vres, NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR , 90);


      # reservamos la pista
   SET @vreserva = (SELECT r.id_reserva FROM reserva AS r 
                      WHERE NEW.login = r.usuario_reserva_login
                      LIMIT 1);
      # cogemos la id de la reserva para ponerla en la clase



    INSERT INTO clase (profesor_login,id_reserva,tipo_clase, jugador_login_1) VALUES ('BELA',@vreserva,'Test de nivel',NEW.login);
      # reservamos la clase con nombre predefinido test de nivel el login de ese nuevo jugador y con un profesor que en este caso sera BELA 


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: una pregunta donde declaras la variable ``@vres`` y donde esta la tabla ``jugador``

Comment: Hola Javier, he modificado lo que puse, ahora esta mas completo, y he añadido la tabla jugador, ahora me hace autoincrement y de forma correcta y me pone la misma id, en la tabla reserva y clase, cuando creo un jugador nuevo. ahora el problema viene en que no me tiene en cuenta el tiempo que dura la reserva y siempre me pone la misma pista si creo varios jugadores.

Comment: vale ahora que tengo la tabla jugador voy a intetar algo

Comment: una pregunta cuando lo ejecutas te funciona sin fallo de sintaxis porque he tenido que hacer pequeñas modificaciones como el delimiter $$ que te falta arriba, te pongo un enlace con tu codigo donde estoy realizando las pruebas https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/29

Comment: ya se por que te pone siempre la misma pista es porque lo limitas a 1 y atraves del id por lo que el valor siempre es el mismo ahora tengo que mirar la manera de solucionarlo

Comment: la verdad que no me daba error, unicamente en el collate, pero el id siempre me sale el mismo, por que ademas siempre me sale el 0

Comment: el error me lo daba porque te comiste el DELIMITER $$ del principio pero te lo he modificado

Comment: Ah vale genial javier, disculpa. Se que para el ID tengo que hacer un select max, pero a pesar de intentarlo no sale

Comment: podemos intentar ordenarlo con un order by id asc y no te haria falta el max(id)

Comment: lo he editado, por que ya he conseguido hacer lo del id, ahora el problema es, que si creo dos jugadores, me saca siempre la misma pista, por el limiter, pero es que si no pongo limiter, me da fallo en la subconsulta por que me muestra mas de 1

Comment: Necesitas proveer más información sobre el problema, por favor revisa las secciones de ayuda de la comunidad para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta.